# left and right subscript and arrow beneath variable

Tags: amsmath, subscripts

Alright, here goes, first I know that my title is somewhat vague, but an image is worth a thousand words, here's what I'm trying to achieve :

[image: desired output]

Now this is the code that I came up with :

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 $P_{CB}$ (ou ${}_{B}\stackrel{P}{\scriptsize{\leftarrow}}_{C}$) telle que
 \end{document}
```

And this is the result of it :

[image: Output]

Now as in the picture, I would like to have the capital P inline with the word "ou" and the arrow to be a smaller size and to have the B and C (left and right) of the capital P as subscripts (maybe?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use \underset?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

With \verb|\underset|:
$P_{CB}$ (ou $\underset{B\leftarrow C}{P}$) telle que 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooooh, I love the output from the underset, didn't know about that one, thanks 

Answer (score 1):

Use provided command `\myfrac` mentioned in your preamble part.
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

```
\newcommand\myfrac[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}


\def\bc{B \leftarrow C}

\begin{document}

$P_{CB}$ (ou $\myfrac{P}{\scriptsize\bc}$) telle que

\end{document}
```

[image]